# How to implement an alarm receiver?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-broadcast

I am starting to learn about the `AlarmManager`, and I want to fire a broadcast to fetch some info from a server. The documentation is clear about the intents and the alarms, but I cannot find anything on how the receiving end should look.

This is my alarm code:

```
AlarmManager aMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
aMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10000, 
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
```

and my `AlarmReceiver` is like this:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Received intent");
    }
}
```

But nothing happens. I added a button to just fire the broadcast like this:

```
public void btnTrigger_onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

and also nothing happens here.

I have used broadcasts before, but only with `registerReceiver`, but I do not want to process the broadcast in my `Activity` now.

Comment: Do you have a `<receiver>` element for `AlarmReceiver` in your manifest?

Comment: @CommonsWare No I hadn't. It was that simple. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicit broadcasts — ones where the `Intent` has the component name (i.e., class) — require a `<receiver>` element in the manifest in order to work.